# OAuth2 authentication error using 'python-o365' library

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, python-3.6

I have able to successfully connect and read emails using the '[python-o365](https://github.com/Narcolapser/python-o365)' library:

```
Connection.oauth2('Client_ID','Client_Secret',store_token=True)
inbox = FluentInbox()
for message in inbox.fetch_next(2):
   print(message.getSubject())
```

However, when I try to send an email using a more basic example, I am receiving a `401` response from the server.

```
Connection.oauth2('Client_ID','Client_Secret',store_token=True)
att = Attachment(path=FilePath)
m = Message()
m.setRecipients(EmailTo)
m.setSubject('DBM Errors Identified - ' + FileName)
m.setBody(MessageBody)
m.attachments.append(att)
m.sendMessage()
```

I have also tried setting the connection object and passing it through as a parameter:

```
auth = Connection.oauth2('Client_ID','Client_Secret',store_token=True)
m = Message(*auth=auth*)
```

That however results in an error message of:

`TypeError: 'Connection' object is not callable`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to bypass the issue by switching to a [fork](https://github.com/janscas/py-o365) of the '[python-o365](https://github.com/Narcolapser/python-o365)' library that I used above. I feel like I am probably missing something obvious with that library but this solved the problem

Here is the simplified version of the authentication flow that I have working in case it interests anyone:

```
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Read'']    
account = Account(('Client_Id', 'Client_Secret'], auth_method='oauth',scopes=scopes)
account.connection.get_authroization_url() #generate the url for user to authenticate
result_url = input('Paste the result URL once you have authenticated...')
account.connection.get_session() #generate a session
m = account.new_message()
m.to.add('EmailTo')
m.body = 'MessageText'
m.send()
```